# header_checks strange behaviour with regexp

Tags: regex, postfix-mta

I have this line in header_checks:

```
/^From:.*finance*./ REJECT
```

When i test it it rejects the message just fine:

```
$ postmap -q "From: xxfinancexx" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks 
REJECT
```

But when I remove the letter E from the word finance it also rejects it, even though it shouldn't.

```
$ postmap -q "From: xxfinancxx" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens? And how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: `postmap -q "From: xxfinancexx" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` doesn't return anything.Please check.

Comment: The asterix where removed some how in the copy paste. The correct data in header_cheks is: /^From:.*finance*./ REJECT

Comment: and this gives REJECT.

Comment: But `postmap -q "From: xxfinancxx" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` returned nothing. Please check.

Comment: No. To me it returns REJECT. Note the asterix in the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong.  `finance*` means `financ` followed by anything (such as, zero or more occurrences of the letter `e`.  You probably mean

```
/^From:.*finance/ REJECT
```

The trailing wildcard (where you had a typo) is redundant; the regex matches even if it doesn't consume the entire input string.  But for the record, the regex for "anything" is `.` (any character) `*` (zero or more times).